# Background of div doesn't center relative to page in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, background, center

I'm attempting to create a frosted glass effect using 2 images, one is the background of the page and one is the background that looks frosted. To achieve this i use the following code:

```
body {
    background: url(interferentie.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

#centerlogo {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background:url(interferentie_lensblur.png) center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

In firefox, this works fine. But in chrome, the background of the div doesn't get centered. You can see an example here: http://www.wavelengthfestival.nl.

In chrome, it appears that the background of the div simply starts where the div starts. does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific it looks center to me. maybe a screenshot would help

Comment: looks good on my end.  Chrome 34 on Ubuntu

Comment: Also looks fine on windows chrome 32

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/f2wa717ct/screen.png

this is a screenshot of what i'm seeing. the div in the center, that contains the wavelength logo, should match the background. in firefox it looks fine: http://s4.postimg.org/p1h8tigsd/correct.png

Answer (score 0):

```
#centerlogo   margin-left:auto   margin-right:auto
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but on top of not displaying the background correctly, the div is now also not centered anymore: http://s30.postimg.org/xw22rd7pt/leftrightauto.png